# .push a Integer into an array is not working JS/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is the code I have so far:

```
   var purseValue = 10000; 
    var storePerson = [];
    var storeAmount = [];  

$('#prompt').keypress(function() {  //
    var whatMyUserTyped = $('#prompt').val();  //Input variable defined for future use.
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {  //If enter is pressed, 
        if (whatMyUserTyped === 'purse'){ //If used types "purse"
            $('#log li:last').text('ShylockBot pulls out his purse containing '+ purseValue+ ' ducat(s)');  
        } else { //log the phrase with total amount in purse. 
    var subtractValue = parseInt(whatMyUserTyped.match(/\d+/));  //scan for the number in my string, then turn into a number.
                var arrayOfInput = whatMyUserTyped.split(" ");
                purseValue = (purseValue - subtractValue); //purse money minus the above sum equals current amount in purse.
                storePerson.push(arrayOfInput[1]);
                storeAmount.push(); //I tried to use the "subtractValue" but for some reason didn't work. So I just selected from string again.
                console.log(storePerson);
                console.log(subtractValue);
```

I am trying to get an user input, I get from that the number they input inside the string, and then I get also their name (Considering the phrase is: "loans person 50 bucks" )

So person would be arrayOfInput[1] and number would be whatever number they type.

Now Im trying to store this values into 2 arrays.

I used .push() which worked fine for "storePerson" and every time my function runs, it adds the input person into it, but the number I can't get it to add to the array. It replaces the array for only one number and doesn't store the old values, which means, replaces storeAmount for the value of the most current input.

I tried to be as clear as I can, even though Im a beginner. So I hope someone can help me. Thanks.

Comment: `match` returns an array, not a string.

Comment: @Oleander is right, so do `whatMyUserTyped.match(/\d+/)[0]`

Comment: Did you forget about adding event as a function param.
    $('#prompt').keypress(function(event)
Or it's just mistake?

Answer (score 1):

I read it multiple times and it just seems like you need to:

`storeAmount.push(subtractValue[0]);
//thanks Orleaner for pointing out that match returns an array`

Were you using double quotes?

PS: Even then, it shouldn't be an issue, it would just add the string "subrtractValue" every time :)

Comment: This is what I was going to say

Comment: Why are you indexing into `subtractValue` which, IIUC, is a number : the result of `parseInt`?  Maybe the `[0]` should attach to the result of the `match` call that is being parsed.

Answer (score -2):

To push an integer into an array in jquery, it must be

storeAmount.push(subtractValue.toString());